# CreateAlias generate Join To a Table Valued function

Tags: nhibernate, join, fluent-nhibernate, criteria, sql-function

Is there a way to extend **CreateAlias** to work with **Table Valued Function** not just tables,
I want to join a **Table Valued Function** to a base table, how can I do this with **Criteria**.

```
SELECT this_.advanceOrderId as y0_  FROM  orders_AdvanceOrders this_
       left outer join AchievableVersions u1_ 
            on this_.unitId = u1_.achievableVersionId
       left  join containstable(AchievableVersions,achievableCode,'ase3002') ct 
            on u1_.achievableVersionId = ct.[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Criteria queries work on entities, not tables.

If your TVF didn't have a parameter, yoy might be able to map it as an entity, but I don't think that's the case.